# how to open Django sample code from github?

Tags: python, django

I am new in Django. I found Tango with Django project code form github. Once downloading it to my local drive, how would I run the sample code locally on my machine and play with it as my own project?

Here is the code:

https://github.com/chadhs/tango-with-django-17

Comment: It looks like you just have to run `manage.py`?

Comment: it says import Error: no module named rest_framework... what's that?

Comment: you need to install django-rest-framework I think

Comment: I did a quick look and it seems to me that there is no dependency on rest_framework. Have you tried install the module that is missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install all the packages mentioned in requirements.txt

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Then `./manage.py runserver`